# How to write the output to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a custom object detection code written in Python using Yolo. I want to write some output values like the image_name, detected_object_label,box_co-ordinate values, confidence percentage into 2 csv files. 1 csv should have image_name, detected_object_label,confidence percentage and the other should have image_name, detected_object_label,box_co-ordinate values

I have made the code for custom object detection till now.

```
import cv2
import glob
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
#import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import json
import sys
import csv
#from utils import label_map_util
#from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from os.path import isfile,join
import pandas as pd


########################################## EXTRACT FRAMES FROM VIDEO###########################


def extractFrames(m):
    global vid_name
    global img_name

    vid_files=glob(m)
    complete_videos = get_completed_videos()
    new_vid_files = [x for x in vid_files if get_vid_name(x) not in complete_videos]

    for vid in new_vid_files:
        print("path of video========>>>>.",vid)

        v1 = os.path.basename(vid)

        try:
            vid_name = get_vid_name(vid)
            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
        except cv2.error as e:
            print(e)
        except:
            print('error')

        fsize = os.stat(vid)
        print('=============size of video ===================:' , fsize.st_size)
        try:

            if ( fsize.st_size > 1000 ):

                fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)      # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
                frameCount = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
                duration = frameCount/fps
                minutes = int(duration/60)
                print('fps = ' + str(fps))
                print('number of frames = ' + str(frameCount))
                print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
                if (duration <= 5):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count=0

                    success=True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"

                        success,image = vidcap.read()
                        if count % 10 == 0 or count ==0:
                            target_non_target(img_name, image)

                        count+=1          

                    vidcap.release()

                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

                elif (duration > 5 and duration <= 10):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%20 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

                elif (duration > 10 and duration <= 20):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%30 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

                elif (duration > 20 and duration <= 100):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%50 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 100 and duration <= 300):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%100 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 300 and duration <= 600):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%150 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 600 and duration <= 900):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%300 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 900 and duration <= 1200):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%600 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

                elif (duration > 1200 and duration <= 1800):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%900 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 1800 and duration <= 3600):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%1200 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 3600 and duration <= 7200):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%1500 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 7200 and duration <= 10800):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%2000 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


                elif (duration > 10800):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()
                    count = 0
                    success = True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                        success,image = vidcap.read()

                        if count%2500 == 0 or count == 0:
                            target_non_target(img_name,image)
                        count+=1
                    vidcap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()                    

                else:
                    print("video length exceeds max limit")

        except:
            print("error")


        print('finished processing video ', vid)
        with open('C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\'+'video_info.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['Video_Name','Process']
            file_is_empty = os.stat('C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\'+'video_info.csv').st_size == 0
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            if file_is_empty:
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'Video_Name':vid_name,'Process':'done'})

        #print('finished processing video {0} with frames {1}'.format(vid_files[v_f], count))


def get_vid_name(vid):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(vid))[0]



def get_completed_videos():
    completed_videos = []
    with open("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\video_info.csv") as csv_file:

        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            for col in range(0,len(row)):
                try:
                    completed_videos.append(row[col])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
    print(completed_videos[0])
    return completed_videos




###########################CHECK FOR TARGET IMAGES FROM FRAMES###########################

def target_non_target(img_name, image):



    try:

        image_re = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))

        image_fl = image_re.astype("float") / 255.0

        image_arr = img_to_array(image_fl)

        image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_arr, axis=0)



        model_file = "C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\target_non_target.model"


        model = load_model(model_file)



        (non_target, target) = model.predict(image_expanded)[0]



        if target > non_target:

            print("[INFO] Target DETECTED...")

            #recognize_object(image)
            draw_pred(image, class_ids[i], confidences[i], round(x), round(y), round(x + w), round(y + h))

        else:

            print("[INFO] NON TARGET...")

    except Exception as e:

        print(str(e))


#################################OBJECT RECOGNITION MODEL CODE################################

#def recognize_object(image):

yolo_cfg = "C:\\Python35\\custom_yolo_object_detector\\darknet\\custom\\yolov3-tiny.cfg"

weights = "C:\\Python35\\custom_yolo_object_detector\\darknet\\custom\\yolov3-tiny_final.weights"

class_names = "C:\\Python35\\custom_yolo_object_detector\\darknet\\custom\\objects.names"


def getOutputsNames(net):
    layersNames = net.getLayerNames()
    return [layersNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

def draw_pred(image, class_id, confidence, x, y, x_plus_w, y_plus_h):

    label = str(classes[class_id])

    color = COLORS[class_id]

    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x_plus_w,y_plus_h), color, 2)

    cv2.putText(img, label, (x-10,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)



classes = None

with open(class_names, 'r') as f:

    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

print(classes)

COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights,yolo_cfg)

image=cv2.resize(image, (299, 299))

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0/255.0, (299,299), [0,0,0], True, crop=False)

Width = image.shape[1]
Height = image.shape[0]

net.setInput(blob)

outs = net.forward(getOutputsNames(net))

class_ids = []
confidences = []
boxes = []
conf_threshold = 0.5
nms_threshold = 0.4

for out in outs:
    for detection in out:
        scores = detection[5:]

        class_id = np.argmax(scores)

        confidence = scores[class_id]

        if confidence > 0.5:

            center_x = int(detection[0] * Width)

            center_y = int(detection[1] * Height)

            w = int(detection[2] * Width)

            h = int(detection[3] * Height)

            x = center_x - w / 2

            y = center_y - h / 2

            class_ids.append(class_id)
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            boxes.append([x, y, w, h])

    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, conf_threshold, nms_threshold)

    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = boxes[i]
        x = box[0]
        y = box[1]
        w = box[2]
        h = box[3]

        #draw_pred(obj_img, class_ids[i], confidences[i], round(x), round(y), round(x+w), round(y+h))

        cv2.putText(image, label, (0, 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .6, (255, 0, 0))

        cv2.imshow(image)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x="C:\\Python36\\videos\\*.mp4"

    extractFrames(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in your values to this function

```
def writeToCSV(value1,value2,value3...):
  with open('new.csv', 'a') as writeFile:
      writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
      for i in range(len(result)):
          writer.writerow(result)
```